# ffmpeg to nginx rtmp on windows got I/O error

Tags: windows, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

1. using https://github.com/illuspas/nginx-rtmp-win32
2. windows server 2018
3. no touch to conf, just illuspas original, run nginx.exe as admin
4. firewall disabled
5. no antivirus
6. service started as a charm, no error in nginx log

run following cmdline as admin

ffmpeg -re -i "rtsp://111.10.31.131:554/pag://192.168
.1.5:7302:001110:0:MAIN:TCP?cnid=2&pnid=1" -f flv -s 640x480 "rtmp://localhost:1
935/live/abc" -loglevel debug

i got this:
see this pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RpNY.jpg

I want to put the rtsp source to a rtmp channel, why im getting this rtsp://***** I/O error? what does that mean? any idea that i could get this rtmp stream?

any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had to give my rtmp sink rights to write at the location (i somehow lost it)